# Why is the Web so complicated?

Tags: web, historical

Hope it does not sound as a surprise to anyone that modern Web and its security, with the many layers and technologies, is pretty confusing and difficult to learn well. For someone with a good perspective on the history of Web's design and development, was there anything that, in hindsight, could have been made simpler; or does the Web have to be so complex because of the requirements it has to meet?

I realize that the question might be broad, but any bits and pieces would be very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is mostly that "the web" is not a singular thing, with a singular designer.

It's a complex structure, who's purpose shifted over decades. We want more from the web today than we wanted back in the 80's, just like we want more from our phones today than we did back in the 80's.

Furthermore, the architectural idea that a server instructs a client to do something, and that client may or may not understand what the server wants, is another reason why the web is so complicated. It's the reason why Internet Explorer is so crappy, and why all web developers rejoiced when Microsoft announced they would finally retire it.

As far as historical data goes, hindsight is always clearer. There are many technologies that we thought were pretty neat (ActiveX, Flash, Java Applets, etc.), but turned out to be horrible in hindsight. Of course, you may look at those things from today's point of view and notice all the problems, but these were designed in a different era, where people had different expectations.

#### To summarize

The Web is complex because

- It grew over decades and is one of the most legacy-loaded things there is.
- It was never designed at one point by one individual or company.
- It had to support many different clients, some of which may be grossly outdated.
- It's not possible to "start over". We can only work with what we have.
- Different companies tried different things, often duplicating work instead of working on open standards.

Comment: What about http? Should have it been designed as stateful from the get-go?

Comment: @postoronnim That's a large question in and of itself, and I'm not sure if it would be a good fit for Security. I would say HTTP is fine as it is.